# Button group stops working on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have added button group to my new website and it seems that two first buttons stop working on smaller screens ? Also if I remove text-center div they all stop working.

http://danielszweda.azurewebsites.net/

I have tried adding , as suggested in some other post, splitting the content to multiple rows, etc. Nothing helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons did not work as they were covered by sidebar wrapper!